# Dropwizard 0.8 and GuiceBundle Governator: Forcing Resources class to be Singleton

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I'm using [Dropwizard 0.8.1](http://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.8.1/) and I have observed that resource object is created each time a belonging path is called.

I think this done because the resource are registered by class when the application is bootstraped.

Is there anyway to force the resources to be Singleton?

I have tried to use `@Singleton` and `@LazySingleton` (via [Governator](https://github.com/ingenieux/dropwizard-governator)) but it seems not to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you specifying `@Singleton` as a class annotation (e.g. `@Singleton class Foo implements Bar {` or in your module binding (e.g. `protected void configure() { bind(Bar.class).to(Foo.class).in(Singleton.class);`)

Comment: in class annotation that's why it does not work

Comment: I'm using a provider for creating the classes how to specify singleton in this case?

Comment: @MasterMind `bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class).in(Singleton.class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guice will override bindings when you specify them as a class annotation. [Documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes):

> If there's conflicting scopes on a type and in a `bind()` statement, the `bind()` statement's scope will be used. If a type is annotated with a scope that you don't want, bind it to `Scopes.NO_SCOPE`.

You can fix this by specifying Singleton in your binding in your `Module`, e.g.

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```